# Default click on a button when component loads in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a button in vue component within `template` as follow:

```
  <a href="#" @click="openTab" class="border-red px-8" id="activeSlide" data-target-quote="#yvoefrance">
    <img :src="inactive_logo[0]" class="logo" alt="yvoefrance logo" />
  </a>
```

I want it to be clicked by default when components loads after refreshing the page, how can I achieve this? I tried following but didn't work for me.

I thought the right place is `created`. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

```
export default {
  name: "component.showcase",
  components: {
    // ...
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // data here....
    };
  },
  created() {
    document.querySelector("#activeSlide").click();
  },
  mounted() {},
  beforeDestroy() {},
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    openTab: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const target_tab = e.target.parentElement.dataset.targetQuote;

      document.querySelector(target_tab).classList.add("active");
      e.target.src = require(`@/assets/img/testimonials/${target_img}_active.png`);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you want to give a bit of context why do you need this ? Also by looking at the button template, it doesn't look you are binding any event listener to it - how do you know it's not working ?

Comment: sure, I will update the question

Comment: and do you get any errors ?

Comment: yes, I get this error `[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button should call a method when clicked:

```html
<button @click="someMethod">Show Content</button>
```

Then you can just call that method programmatically from a lifecycle hook instead of trying to manually trigger a click on the button:

```js
methods: {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod called');
  }
},
created() {
  this.someMethod();  // Run the button's method when created
}
```

---

EDIT to match your edit:

You are using DOM manipulation but should manipulate data instead and let Vue handle the DOM.  Here is a basic example of how you can do what you want:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      logos: [
        {
          urlInactive: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000/FFFFFF',
          urlActive: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFFFF/000000',
          isActive: false
        },
        {
          urlInactive: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/666666/FFFFFF',
          urlActive: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/999999/000000',
          isActive: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive(logo) {
      logo.isActive = !logo.isActive;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <a v-for="logo in logos" @click="toggleActive(logo)">
    <img :src="logo.isActive ? logo.urlActive : logo.urlInactive" />
  </a>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```